# Mod_rewrite replace specific string at the end of the url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to replace the last piece of a url with a specific id.

I can use :-

```
RewriteRule ^tester-affiliate index.php?ID=8 [NC,L] # rewrite the affiliate url
```

if the url is just `domain.tid/tester-affiliate`

but what if the url is `domain.tid/category/product/tester-affiliate`

I need the url to be written as `domain.tid/category/product/index.php?ID=8`

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)tester-affiliate $1/index.php?ID=8 [L,NC]
```

Anything that comes before `tester-affiliate` would get captured by the regex `(.*)` and backreferenced using `$1`.